# Splitting time into hour intervals in oracle (CTE)

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

So, my aim is to be able to count time spent on certain activities in hour ranges.

My data contains: start of the certain activity and end of that activity,
for example I know that someone had break from '2019-01-09 17:04:34' to '2019-01-09 19:55:03'.

My aim is to calculate that this person spent 55 minutes on break in interval '17-18', 60 minutes on '18-19' and 55 minutes on '19-20'.

My idea was to always split the source so for the row containing start and and of the activity I would receive as many rows as my time range split in the hour ranges (for this sample data I would receive 3: rows with '2019-01-09 17:04:34' to '2019-01-09 17:59:59', '2019-01-09 18:00:00' to '2019-01-09 18:59:59' and '2019-01-09 19:00:00' to '2019-01-09 19:55:03')

If I could obtain something like that I could manage to count all things I need to. I predict that to obtain this result I should use CTE (as we don't know in how many ranges we need to split time interval), but I have no experience in it.

Hopefully I managed to explain my problem clearly. I work on oracle sql developer.

I'd be very grateful for your help on at least some tips.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried crossjoining data with the table consisted of minutes and checking if these minutes are between start and end of activity and then grouping over hours. Unfortunalety these idea  doesn't seem to be very optimal. It takes very long to receive results. So I came up with the idea to use the recurrence..

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned recursion, this uses recursive subquery factoring:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with your_table (id, start_time, end_time) as (
  select 1, timestamp '2019-01-09 17:04:34', timestamp '2019-01-09 19:55:03' from dual
  union all
  select 2, timestamp '2019-01-09 23:47:01', timestamp '2019-01-10 02:05:03' from dual
  union all
  select 3, timestamp '2019-01-09 18:01:01', timestamp '2019-01-09 18:02:07' from dual
  union all
  select 4, timestamp '2019-01-09 13:00:00', timestamp '2019-01-09 14:00:01' from dual
),
-- recursive CTE
rcte (id, hour_period, minutes, period_start_time, end_time, hour_num) as (
  select id,
    -- first period is the original start hour
    extract(hour from start_time),
    -- minutes in first period, which can end at the end of that hour, or at original
    -- end time if earlier
    case when extract(minute from end_time) = 0
         and end_time >= cast(trunc(start_time, 'HH') as timestamp) + interval '1' hour
         then 60
         else extract(minute from
           least(cast(trunc(start_time, 'HH') as timestamp) + interval '1' hour, end_time)
           - start_time
         )
    end,
    -- calculate next period start
    cast(trunc(start_time, 'HH') as timestamp) + interval '1' hour,
    -- original end time
    end_time,
    -- first hour period (for later ordering)
    1
  from your_table
  union all
  select id,
    -- this period's hour value
    extract(hour from period_start_time),
    -- minutes in this period - either 60 if we haven't reach the end time yet;
    -- or if we have then the number of minutes from the end time
    case when end_time < period_start_time + interval '1' hour
         then extract(minute from end_time)
         else 60
    end,
    -- calculate next period start
    period_start_time + interval '1' hour,
    -- original end time
    end_time,
    -- increment hour period (for later ordering)
    hour_num + 1
  from rcte
  where period_start_time < end_time
)
select id, hour_period, minutes
from rcte
order by id, hour_num;
```

```
        ID HOUR_PERIOD    MINUTES
---------- ----------- ----------
         1          17         55
         1          18         60
         1          19         55
         2          23         12
         2           0         60
         2           1         60
         2           2          5
         3          18          1
         4          13         60
         4          14          0
```

It find finds the amount of time spent in the first hour of the period in the anchor member, then recursively looks at subsequent hours until the end time is reached, increasing the passed-on period end time each time; and in the recursive member it checks whether to use a fixed 60 minutes (if it knows the end time hasn't been reached) or use the actual minutes from the end time.

My example periods include ones that span midnight, cover less than an hour, and that start in the first minute of an hour - and which end in the first minute of an hour, which (in my calculation anyway) ends up with a row for that hour anyway and the number of minutes as zero. You can easily filter that out if you don't want to see it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear from your post how you want to handle non-zero seconds components (what combination of rounding and/or truncation). In any case, that can be coded easily, once a complete set of non-contradictory rules is agreed upon.

Other than that, your question consists of two parts: identify the proper hours for each id (each activity or event), and the duration of the part of that event during that hour. In the query below, using the `CONNECT BY` hierarchical technique, I generate the hours and the duration as an interval day to second. As I said, that can be converted to minutes (between 0 and 60) once you clarify the rounding rules.

```
with
  your_table (id, start_time, end_time) as (
    select 1, timestamp '2019-01-09 17:04:34', timestamp '2019-01-09 19:55:03' 
    from dual union all
    select 2, timestamp '2019-01-09 23:47:01', timestamp '2019-01-10 02:05:03'
    from dual union all
    select 3, timestamp '2019-01-09 18:01:01', timestamp '2019-01-09 18:02:07'
    from dual union all
    select 4, timestamp '2019-01-09 13:00:00', timestamp '2019-01-09 14:00:01'
    from dual
  )
select id,
       trunc(start_time, 'hh') + interval '1' hour * (level - 1) as hr,
       case when level = 1 and connect_by_isleaf = 1 
              then end_time - start_time
            when level = 1                           
              then trunc(start_time, 'hh') + interval '1' hour - start_time
            when connect_by_isleaf = 1 
              then end_time - trunc(end_time, 'hh')
            else interval '1' hour
       end  as duration
from   your_table
connect by trunc(start_time, 'hh') + interval '1' hour * (level - 1) < end_time
       and prior id = id
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
;
```

**Output**:

```
        ID HR                  DURATION           
---------- ------------------- -------------------
         1 2019-01-09 17:00:00 +00 00:55:26.000000
         1 2019-01-09 18:00:00 +00 01:00:00.000000
         1 2019-01-09 19:00:00 +00 00:55:03.000000
         2 2019-01-09 23:00:00 +00 00:12:59.000000
         2 2019-01-10 00:00:00 +00 01:00:00.000000
         2 2019-01-10 01:00:00 +00 01:00:00.000000
         2 2019-01-10 02:00:00 +00 00:05:03.000000
         3 2019-01-09 18:00:00 +00 00:01:06.000000
         4 2019-01-09 13:00:00 +00 01:00:00.000000
         4 2019-01-09 14:00:00 +00 00:00:01.000000
```